# Apple Web App Startup Image Delay

Tags: ios, iphone, image

Is there any way to make the start image delay?

I have all the resolutions and images fine

```
<head> 
  <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="startup.png" /> 
<head>
```

But the image goes very fast, I wish I could make it appear longer, like 2/3 seconds. So the user can see it better.

**Edit**

After the answer from @Jens Kohl, I included a small sleep with PHP on the head section, just after the startup image link :)

It's working fine now

```
<?php
  sleep(2); //wait 2 seconds
?>
```

Comment: Please don't. Think of your users. Why force an artificial delay?

Comment: It's one second delay, without it the 'web app' appears to be broken. It flashes like a white screen, very fast. Check any startup of any official ios app. It's like 3 seconds or more. Check the TRULIA app, you will understand. It's slow, you can see everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startup image is not supposed to stall the user. It's supposed to be a placeholder to cover up the startup time.

That said, you could probably insert a wait/sleep JavaScript call inside your head-Tag.

Comment: Where should I put that? And how? Any example? Thanks

Comment: Perfect, added the php sleep after the images codes :)